# .htaccess pretty URLs are not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls, pretty-urls

I'm trying to use pretty URLs on my site, and I don't know too much about htaccess, but after some search I ended up with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ content.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC]
```

I'm trying to change this:

> mysite.com/cms/content.php?action=content&id=80

into:

> mysite.com/cms/content/80

But somehow it's not working and what I get is a blank screen and a 404 error,

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) --in-- /cms/files/plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js
```

About the 404 error: It should load a .js file from mystie.com/files/plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js -- not -- mystie.com/cms/files/plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js

My htaccess file is in the root folder. Am I doing something wrong?

I think the server did not read my .htaccess file. How do I find out the issue?

Comment: @anubhava it's in root. have a one 404 error, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) --in-- /cms/files/plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js

Comment: Is `/cms/` a wordpress installation? Does `/cms/` folder also have a .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava no in cms is my own cms. there isn't any htaccess in /cms. in prev answer, about 404 error. it should load .js file from mystie.com/files/plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js -- not -- mystie.com/cms/files/plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js -- what's the problem?

Comment: Added the info on the comments to your question and Improved some formatting and grammar

Comment: ok, thanks for edit. and sorry for my bad english @FabioAntunes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place this rule in `/cms/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms/

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ content.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Then you need add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: **`<base href="/" />`** so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's relative URL.

Comment: this code also not working. i think the problem is something else.

Comment: thanks, now i know htaccess working fine. also your answer works perfectly, but css or not loaded, i'm working on it, i think need to change base or src .. thanks for your great help.

Comment: it's already have this. but css will redirect. css is in css/style.css but it redirect to cms/style.css, should i change css src to /cms/style/style.css ?

Comment: Yes it is always better to use full path like that. If you css/js are in `/cms/` then you need to use: `<base href="/cms/" />` in `head` section of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have `/cms/` in your URL before the rest, so you need to change `RewriteRule` to something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^cms/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ content.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC]
```

Also, I hope you are aware that .htaccess can not work on some servers (like [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) or some custom ones), and even on [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) servers there can be `mod_rewrite` disabled.

Comment: still not working.. yes you right but i have checked before on another website in this server. tested on wordpress and other cms with pretty urls plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/cms/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ content.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC]
```

Remove escape slashes \

Comment: yet it's not working. still blank screen. what's the problem?

Comment: If your htaccess is inside cms folder remove /cms from rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your scripts and styles are being linked to via relative URLs. Because the old URL is `/cms/content.php` the URI base is `/cms/` and your relative links all resolved to be under `/cms/`, which I assume is what you want.

However, when you change your links to `/cms/content/1234`, the URI base becomes `/cms/content/` and all relative links will use this as its base, and since "content" isn't even a real folder, all those links will 404, and you won't load any of your CSS content or scripts.

Either change your links to absolute URLs or specify a URI base in the header of your pages (inside the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/cms/" />
```

Comment: this also not working. anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to include the subfolder if your htaccess is in the root.
Try this rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cms/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /cms/content.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Also a blank screen usually means a PHP error.